# Which class loader loads class from -Dcp and which classloader loads classes from EAR?

Tags: java, weblogic, classloader

I have a doubt regrading classloading. I am deploying my EAR on Weblogic. This Ear contains several jars. While starting the WebLogic I am defining **-cp** in startweblogic.sh.

I want to understand the class loading in this scenario. Jars added in **-cp** will be loaded by which class loader and jars packaged in EAR will be loaded by which class loader ?

Will both of them considered as separate applications ? and accordingly loaded by application class loader ?

Could anyone please help me understand this ?